# Как запустить несколько приложений под разными проксями?

Tags: windows, proxy

Я пробовал через sandboxie и proxifier в каждой, но это постоянно приводило к ошибкам. Да и как-то сложно это. Думаю, есть способ легче, чем создавать кучу песочниц и проксификатором.

Задача: есть 10 софтин. Нужно каждую запустить под разной проксей. В самом софте настройки сети выставлять нельзя. Подскажите, пожалуйста, софт, с помощью которого такое можно реализовать. Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

разобрался с proxifier.Оказывается можно и 100 прокси одновременно там включить...